# click function not showing element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show elements when a checkbox is checked and hide them when unchecked.

```
for (var id = 1; id <= N; id++) {
    var $newSlider = $("<div/>", {
        id: 'slider-' + id,
        class: 'ui-slider'
    }).slider({
        range: 'min',
        min: initVal,
        max: N,
        value: initVal,
        step: 2,
        slide: function( event, ui) {
            $newResult.val( ui.value );
        }
    });
    var $newResult = $('<input/>', {
        type: 'text',
        id: 'result-' + id,
        class: 'sliderText',
        value: '4'
    });
    var $x = $("<div/>", {
        id: 'sliderContainer-' + id
    }).append($newResult).append($newSlider);
    $("#showSldr").append($x);
}
```

This is the function to show/hide them but it's not working:

```
$("body").on("click", "#showChck input", function() {
    show_hide_sliders();
});

function show_hide_sliders() {
    $("#showSldr>div").hide();
    $("#showChck input").filter(":checked").filter(":visible").each(function() {
        var id = this.id.replace(/\D/g, '');
        $('#sliderContainer' + id).show();
    });
}
```

The problem must be something I didn't notice...

The truth is originally the sliders (each one) were created the first time a checkbox is checked: http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/6vkyh4kL/10/

But I prefer to have them created and just show/hide, so that no matter what checkbox you check first they will always be in order (from 1 to 30): http://jsfiddle.net/6vkyh4kL/13/

Comment: I don't understand. The first fiddle link seems to work no ?

Comment: Yes, the first fiddle creates a slider the first time a checkbox is checked (they have the number in common), then just hides and shows it. I'd like to created them at once (like the checkboxes) and just use the show_hide_sliders() function.

Comment: Could it be only the hyphen missing in your show function? $('#sliderContainer-' + id).show();

Comment: A mistake like that is embarrassing. Thank you!